# How to import data into CRM Dynamics 2013 when user clicks a ribbon button

Tags: javascript, wcf, windows-services, dynamics-crm-2013

I have a scenario where I need to import some data from an excel spreadsheet into CRM Dynamics , a user will click the upload ribbon button then the data must be imported problematically, I am aware of Data-import in CRM and that is what I want to build, my issue is how can I build this so that the ribbon triggers the import, do i build a WCF service that does the import and then call it on JavaScript in ribbon, is this possible? or as a windows service? Please assist with a better approach. Can a WCF service be triggers from CRM ribbon button using JavaScript or a Windows service.

Comment: what is wrong with the existing Data Import? (ie why do you want to redesign it?)  you click the button and it opens up a wizard which finishes with the import process being triggered.  Do you want to get rid of the wizard?

Comment: Hi Joseph ,The reason I want to build it custom is that on import of the data I need to perform data validation on the data on fields such as email address and so on,unless you saying its possible to perform validation with the Wizard. If you, how can I archive this?

Comment: you can perform validation a number of ways depending on what type of validation.  you can do duplicate detection by setting up rules - then marking (in the wizard) to not allow duplicates.  You can also write a plugin on the create of the records that are being imported.  You can write whatever validation you want in the plugin, then you can choose whether to block that particular record from being imported or allowing it anyway (register the plugin as synchronous, and then throw an InvalidPluginExecutionException if you want to block the create of the record)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for dummy answer, but it is my first on SO :).
I've complete the same solution recently. I've  do it by parsing Excel data with [ODS parser and writer](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) then i've update the records with the [XRMServiceTolkit](https://xrmservicetoolkit.codeplex.com). It is completely client-side solution. You did not necessary to build any WCF-services or something.

Here it is my sample:

1. Pass Excel file into the dialog;
2. After you pass the Excel file, you need to convert it data to BinaryString. For Cross-Browser support (so as the readAsBinaryString is depricated):

   ```
   function toBinaryString(buffer) {
       var binary = '';
       var bytes = new Uint8Array(buffer);
       var length = bytes.byteLength;
       for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
           binary += String.fromCharCode(bytes[i]);
       }
       return binary;
    }
   ```
3. And parser call function (using ODS parser):

   ```
   function handleFile(inputFile) {
       var files = inputFile.files;
       var i, f;
       for (i = 0, f = files[i]; i != files.length; ++i) {
          var reader = new FileReader();
          var name = f.name;
          reader.onload = function (e) {
              var resultLog = "";
              var data = toBinaryString(e.target.result);
              var workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'binary' });
              if (workbook.Sheets.hasOwnProperty("List")) {
                  var str = workbook.Sheets["List"];
                  var rowsCount = parseInt(str["!ref"].substring(str["!ref"].indexOf(":") + 2));
                  for (var i = 2; i <= rowsCount; i++) {
                      var rowNum = i;
                      var aoName = str.hasOwnProperty("A" + i.toString()) ? str["A" + i.toString()].v : "-";
                      var aoOp = str.hasOwnProperty("B" + i.toString()) ? str["B" + i.toString()].v : "-";
                      var aoSig = str.hasOwnProperty("C" + i.toString()) ? str["C" + i.toString()].v : "-";
                      var aoStatus = str.hasOwnProperty("D" + i.toString()) ? str["D" + i.toString()].v : "-";
                      var aoComment = str.hasOwnProperty("E" + i.toString()) ? str["E" + i.toString()].v : "-";
                      var validateResult = valdateData(rowNum, aoName, aoOp, aoSig, aoStatus, aoComment);
                      resultLog += validateResult ? validateResult : submitRecord(rowNum, aoName, aoOp, aoSig, aoStatus, aoComment);
           }
       }
   };
   reader.readAsArrayBuffer(f);
   ```

   }
   }